# Domain Webmail cannot be accessed with browser

Tags: networking, email, domain, web

When opening http://mail.domain.com/ in a browser, it returns the following error:

> This site can’t be reached mail.futabamfi.com.kh took too long to respond.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

So how do I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: All this error means is that the browser couldn't connect to the site. If you have an internet connection otherwise, then there is likely an issue with the server itself, the physical path to the server (i.e. the internet connection outside your local network, which you can do nothing about) or the domain name (which is the website owner's responsibility).